# Piped ts prevents shell script from exiting

Tags: bash, pipe, tee

I have a problem with my new backup script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#################################################
###########   Backup-Copy-Skript ##############
#################################################

set -o pipefail

case "$1" in
    largehistory)
            logger "Largehistory Backup gestartet..."
            /usr/bin/rsnapshot -c /etc/rsnapshot_largehistory.conf daily | ts '%a %d-%m-%Y %T ' | tee -a  /var/log/rsnapshot_largehistory_verbose.log

            /root/scripts/copyJob.sh copyjob copydrive /mnt/backupdrive/ /mnt/copydrive/ | ts '%a %d-%m-%Y %T ' | tee -a /var/log/copybackup.log
            logger "Largehistory Backup beendet..."
            ;;
    smallhistory)
            logger "Smallhistory Backup gestartet..."
            /usr/bin/rsnapshot -c /etc/rsnapshot_smallhistory.conf daily | ts '%a %d-%m-%Y %T ' | tee -a /var/log/rsnapshot_smallhistory_verbose.log
            logger  "Smallhistory Backup beendet..."
            ;;
esac

exit 0
```

The script should run rsnapshot and after this call another script thats open a luks disk, copy the backup and close the luks disk.

For log and debug purpose i pipe the commands to ts and tee so I get a usefull log what's happend:

```
`Fri 01-10-2021 11:07:01      /etc/rsnapshot_smallhistory.conf daily: completed successfully`
```

But the problem is, the the script does not exit!

pstree shows that after a backup:

```
root@apu:~# pstree
systemd─┬─agetty
        ├─cron───cron───sh───backup.sh─┬─tee
        │                              └─ts
        ├─dbus-daemon
        ├─nmbd
        ├─rsyslogd───3*[{rsyslogd}]
        ├─smartd
        ├─smbd─┬─cleanupd
        │      ├─lpqd
        │      └─smbd-notifyd
        ├─sshd───sshd───sshd───bash───su───bash───pstree
        ├─systemd───(sd-pam)
        ├─systemd-journal
        ├─systemd-logind
        ├─systemd-timesyn───{systemd-timesyn}
        └─systemd-udevd
```

When I kill tee, ts persist further and the script is still alive. When I kill ts, tee will killed and the script exiting. Ts keeps tee and the script alive, but I don't understand why.

I have tried to add set -o pipefail to prevent this, but it doesn't help.

Can anybody explain me what is happend and how I can prevent this?

### **EDIT:**

The script runs on Debian 10 and a execution of the script shows this output:

```
root@apu:~# /root/scripts/backup.sh largehistory
umount: /mnt/copydrive: not mounted.
Mon 11-10-2021 16:30:34  Aktualisiere Festplatten..
Mon 11-10-2021 16:31:06  Luksopen sdc1 mit Key /mnt/backupdrive/.crypto/copydrive.keyfile als copydrive
Device /dev/sdc1 doesn`t exist or access denied.
Device /dev/sde1 doesn`t exist or access denied.
Mon 11-10-2021 16:31:09  fsck from util-linux 2.33.1 e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
Mon 11-10-2021 16:31:11  /dev/mapper/copydrive: recovering journal
Mon 11-10-2021 16:31:12  /dev/mapper/copydrive: clean, 3222603/183144448 files, 805556469/1465126144 blocks
Mon 11-10-2021 16:31:12  mount /dev/mapper/copydrive in /mnt/copydrive
Mon 11-10-2021 16:31:12  Gemountet
Mon 11-10-2021 16:31:12  /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 10\% -c5\% -p /mnt/copydrive -u GB
Mon 11-10-2021 16:31:12  DISK OK - free space: /mnt/copydrive 2236 GB (42% inode=98%);| /mnt/copydrive=3027GB;4988;5265;0;5543
Mon 11-10-2021 16:31:12  0
Mon 11-10-2021 16:31:12  Starte Rsync auf copydrive
Tue 12-10-2021 06:08:58  Starte Dateivergleich
Tue 12-10-2021 10:18:38  Backupkopie komplett
Tue 12-10-2021 10:18:38  /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 10\% -c5\% -p /mnt/copydrive -u GB
Tue 12-10-2021 10:18:38  DISK OK - free space: /mnt/copydrive 2074 GB (39% inode=98%);| /mnt/copydrive=3190GB;4988;5265;0;5543
Tue 12-10-2021 10:18:38  0
root@apu:~#
```

The script is finished but runs in the background (see pstree output above)

My only suggestion would be to query the pid of ts to kill it.
It works but this can't be the solution...

Comment: Which linux distribution is it ? Have you tried to run it on the command line ?

Comment: What is the specific command you use to launch this script?  Show your complete output in the question (as text, not an image).